# checkbox make invisible input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a query in php that collects the products from the table and presses them, I want that by clicking on the checkbox I make the input visible, I have this until now:

```
<?php
$conn->conectar();
$query = "SELECT * FROM c_ingredientes WHERE precio = '5'";
try {
    $resp = $conn->obtDatos($query);
    if ($conn->filasConsultadas > 0) {
        foreach ($resp as $dts) {
            $id = $dts['id'];
            $ingrediente = $dts['ingrediente'];

            echo "<style>
                #quiantitynice{ 
                    display: none;
                }
                </style>
                <div name=\"quiantitynice$id\">
                    <input type=\"number\" name=\"quantity$id\">
                </div>";

            echo "<div class=\"form-check\">
                    <input class=\"form-check-input\" name=\"extra\" type=\"checkbox\" id=\"extra$id\" value=\"$id\">
                    <label class=\"form-check-label\" for=\"extra$id\">" . utf8_encode($ingrediente) . "</label>
                </div>";
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex;
}
$conn->cerrar();
?>
```

This is what I have in script but I do not know how to connect it because each checkbox has its name + PHP id and they are already generated:

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#extra').on('change', function() {
                if (this.checked) {
                    $("#quantity$id").show();
                } else {
                    $("#quantity&id").hide();
                }
            })
        });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by these steps;

1. First get the **value** of the checkbox that you click.
2. And check if the checkbox is checked or not.
3. If it is checked show the input that is related to the checkbox that  you clicked by concatenating the **id string** of the input with the **value** that you get from checkbox.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[name="extra"]').on('change',function () { 
    var _thisVal = $(this).val();
    
    if (this.checked) {
      $("#quiantitynice" + _thisVal).show();
    } else {
      $("#quiantitynice" + _thisVal).hide();
    }

  });

});
```

```css
.quiantitynice { 
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" name="extra" type="checkbox" id="extra1" value="1">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="extra1">ingredientname1</label>
</div>

<div class="quiantitynice" id="quiantitynice1">
  <input type="number" name="quantity1">
</div>

<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" name="extra" type="checkbox" id="extra$id" value="2">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="extra1">ingredientname2</label>
</div>

<div class="quiantitynice" id="quiantitynice2">
  <input type="number" name="quantity2">
</div>
```

Comment: Please avoid posting code-only answers.  Please take a moment and write some semblance of an explanation in plain terms.  Even easy solutions are worthy of some explanation.

Comment: @mickmackusa thz for the advice. by the way I am new to stackoverflow. :)

Comment: I know.  That's why I politely asked.